# Customize SUMPRODUCT to multiply an array by a specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to figure out how to use the SUMPRODUCT function to multiply one of the arrays by a value.  I have pasted my formula that is not working right now below.  I am going to be using this formula about 60 times incrementing the `C68` cell over one to the right each time. The cells `$R$4:$R$61` contain a fraction that tells me the number of months a project will last.  So a 5 month project will have a value of 1/5.  I want to multiply this value by the number of months elapsed at time `c68`, which is a date cell.  I know that the MAX(MONTH()) function works, I just don't know how to multiply it to the cells in column R.

Thanks for the help!

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($H$4:$H$61<C68)*($K$4:$K$61>C68),$E$4:$E$61,$R$4:$R$61*(MAX(MONTH(C68-$H$4:$H$61),0)))
```

Comment: As soon as you multiply a boolean by a number or another boolean, it becomes a number. You do not need the double-unary at the beginning to convert the two booleans multiplied against each other..

Comment: In the end, I want a formula that says: if the cells in column H are less than C68 AND the cells in column K are greater than C68, then sum the products of column E, column R, and the month calculation.

Comment: MAX only ever returns a single value, never an array of values. Were you hoping for the portion MAX(MONTH(C68-$H$4:$H$61),0) to resolve to an 'array of maxes', i.e. composed of either 0 or the result of MONTH(C68-Hxxx) for rows xxx, where 4<=xxx<=61?

Comment: @XORLX I suppose I don't need the MAX function.  All I want is for the column R values to be multiplied by the number of months elapsed at date `C68`.  I can not do this as a new column and add it the sumproduct formula as a new array because I would need 60 new columns for all 60 dates I am looking at.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So with the MAX portion removed, why doesn't your formula above give the desired results?

Comment: @XORLX I am not sure.  I get a #NUM! error.

Comment: I figured it out... I needed an absolute value around the month calculation.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Ok, glad you worked it out!

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of ABS & SUMPRODUCT, The SUMPRODUCT formula takes only arrays as input. So we will input an array using ABS formula.
E.g:

- Array: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 stored at B1:B6
- We want to multiply a specific value stored in A1, and get the sum of their products
- The output of ABS(B1:B6*A1) can be used as an array type input to our SUMPRODUCT formula.
- Finally SUMPRODUCT(ABS(B1:B6*A1)), this will result in the multiplication of all the number in the reference cells with the constant in the cell A1 and output the Sum of all this.

Your formula should look like SUMPRODUCT(ABS($R$4:$R$61*C68)) as far as only one array is concerned. Hope this helps.